# Write a program that prompts the user to enter a string, then displays the total number of characters and total number of lower case characters

Tags: java, string, char

I am a beginner so please help me! so the goal is to write a program in simple java that will ask someone to enter a string, then prints the total characters, as well as the total lower case characters, here is what I have so far...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string");
        String s = input.nextLine;
        String lower = "";
        String total = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char thisChar = s.charAt(i);
        } if (thisChar >= 97 && thisChar <= 122) {
            lower += thisChar;
        }

        System.out.println("Total amount of characters: " + s.length() + " - " + s);
        System.out.println("Lower case letters: " + lower.length() + " - " + lower);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Now, what's the problem?

Comment: You get an error? Something else? Exception?

Comment: BTW: You will get a surprise if you ever get non-BMP characters or combining characters: `string.length()` only gives the number of UTF-16 codeunits, not Unicode characters.

Comment: Accept the answer which helped you more, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a string");
    String s = input.nextLine();// methods should be called with () even if have no argument

    String lower = "";
    String total = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char thisChar = s.charAt(i);
        // you can replace with : if (Character.isLowerCase(thisChar))
        if (thisChar >= 97 && thisChar <= 122) {
            lower += thisChar;
        }
    }//close the for loop here

    System.out.println("Total amount of characters: " + s.length() + " - " + s);
    System.out.println("Lower case letters: " + lower.length() + " - " + lower);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the question?

It looks like you closed your "for" loop earlier than you should

Answer (score 0):

- nextLine is a method so it should be followed by parenthesis. `nextLine()`
- If you compare a char with char, the compiler will automatically compare them using their ASCII, so you don't have to know the ASCII of any letter, just insert the char as it is.
- The if statement should be in the for loop, it makes sense ;)

Check this code for better understanding.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string");
        String s = input.nextLine();

        String lower = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char thisChar = s.charAt(i);

            if (thisChar >= 'a' && thisChar <= 'z') {
                lower += thisChar;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Total amount of characters: " + s.length() + " - " + s);
        System.out.println("Lower case letters: " + lower.length() + " - "+ lower);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `Scanner.nextLine()` is a method, not a variable so you should put the `()` after it. Look at your `String s = input.nextLine;` and change it to `String s = input.nextLine();`
2. Braces

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
       char thisChar = s.charAt(i);
   } if (thisChar >= 97 && thisChar <= 122) {
       lower += thisChar;
   }
   ```

   as you can see, the first `}` closes the `for` so it means: `thisCar` will not be anymore visible and you cannot use it outside! Change it to

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
       char thisChar = s.charAt(i);
    if (thisChar >= 97 && thisChar <= 122) {
       lower += thisChar;
    }
   }
   ```
3. Use 'a' and 'z' as range. So the if will be

   ```
   if (thisChar >= 'a' && thisChar <= 'z') {
   ```
4. You don't need a total variable.
5. Use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) if you need to create a string, you will avoid the creation of useless temporary strings.

### Logic

1. You need to only count the number of lowercase letters or show too? If the former, just use a integer variable and increment it everytime instead of put everything inside lower String.

   ```
   int lower = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
       char thisChar = s.charAt(i);
      if (thisChar >= 'a' && thisChar <= 'z') {
         lower ++;
     }
   }
   ```