# Write a program that asks the user to enter positive intergers,and prints out if any of the intergers are Multiple of 2, 3 or 5 , 7 or 9 but not both

Tags: java

So basically this program has to prompt the user to enter values, and keeps prompting until the user enters -1.

If any of those integers applies, it prints out `MultipleOfTwo`, `MultipleOfThreeAndFive`, or `MultipleOfSevenOrNineButNotBoth`. Here is what I have so far. Please help me finish this up!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Enter Positive Values");
            int num = input.nextInt();
            if num = -1
        }
        break;
    }

    int i = 1;

    while (i <= 1) {

        if (num % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.print("MultipleOfTwo");
            else if (num % 3 == 0 && num % 5 == 0)
                System.out.print("MultipleOfThreeAndFive");
            else if (num % 7 == 0 ^ num % 9 == 0)
                System.out.print("MultipleOfSevenOrNine");
            else
                System.out.print("Invalid");
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

I had it working but I couldn't figure out how to have the program to keep asking for more integers. Any help will be appreciated thank you!

Comment: So it basically has to prompt the user to enter and integer, until they enter -1. then print out any of those conditions that apply

Comment: You might try googling "fizzbuzz"

Comment: ever since i added the first while loop it couldnt get it to compile

Comment: Use indentation. It makes life a lot easier.

Comment: I spotted a compiler error right away, no actually those are two: if num = -1 }
break;
}

Comment: Too much of this isn't legal Java - `if num = -1 }` ??

Comment: Am sure I've seen this question with a `code-trolling` tag on code golf

Comment: By the way, rather than testing if a number is a multiple of two by testing the remainder of N / 2, it would generally be more efficient to test the Least Significant Bit. If the LSB is set, it is odd and therefore not divisible by two. `if (num & 1) // Not divisible by 2`

Comment: I'm wrong or & and | are slow? (well, i don't know if true in Java, that's why i ask.)

Comment: In this another answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047763/write-a-program-that-prompts-the-user-to-enter-a-string-then-displays-the-total ; accept the answer which helped you more. Don't leave Questions without an answer if useful.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno: Bitwise operations are lot quicker than division on most CPU architectures. The only exception I can think of would be older GPUs, which were horrible at integer operations.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno If you mean in a boolean context, they potentially would be slower if the expression would short-circuit otherwise.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman, Azar: Ok thanks, time ago i worked with a language which AND/OR operations are for some strange reason very slow and i never informed myself if java has the same problem. Thanks anyway. -- OP: I love how your question titles are so similar, you copy the title of the homework and paste it directly. love it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a homework dump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (true)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Positive Values");
    int num = input.nextInt();
    if (num < 0) break;

    if (num % 2 == 0)
        System.out.print("MultipleOfTwo");
    else if (num % 3 == 0 && num % 5 == 0)
        System.out.print("MultipleOfThreeAndFive");
    else if (num % 7 == 0 && num % 9 == 0)
        System.out.print("MultipleOfSevenOrNine");
    else
        System.out.print("Invalid");
}
```

Comment: Can you do my homework too please?

Comment: Give a man a fish and you teach him to beg for code -- shameful. Teach a man to fish -- better.

Comment: I can't say I disagree, but sometimes you can learn how to fish by people showing you how they do it.

Comment: The original poster has posted at least two questions that were essentially nothing but homework dumps. My own philosophy is that we shouldn't be encouraging this behavior in him.

Comment: All I did was copy-paste his code into my answer and do a little cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

Just

```
int num = 0;
while(num != -1){
System.out.println("Enter Positive Values");
num = input.nextInt();
}
```

If you declare `num` inside the while you can't use it outside and you don't need a if to break it, just use it as condition. (More [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScope.htm).)

P.S I'm sure you want to move

```
if (num % 2 == 0)
System.out.print("MultipleOfTwo");
else if (num % 3 == 0 && num % 5 == 0)
System.out.print("MultipleOfThreeAndFive");
else if (num % 7 == 0 ^ num % 9 == 0)
System.out.print("MultipleOfSevenOrNine");
else
System.out.print("Invalid");
```

inside the `while`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a BufferedReader

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

and then in your loop

```
int someInt;
while(someCondition()){
    someInt = Integer.parseInteger(br.readLine());
    //your code here
}
```

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int num = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
while (num >= 0) {
    // do logic
    num = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
}
```